# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode escaping too much?

Tags: asp.net, .net, unicode, utf-8, razor

In our MVC3 ASP.net project, the HttpUtility.HtmlEncode method seems to be escaping too much characters. Our web pages are served as UTF-8 pages, but still the method escapes characters like ü or the Yen character ¥, even though tese characters are part of the [UTF-8 set](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/).

So when my asp.net MVC view contains the following piece of code:

```
    @("<strong>ümlaut</strong>")
```

Then I would expect the Encoder to escape the html tags, but *not* the ümlaut

```
    &lt;strong&gt;ümlaut&lt;/strong&gt;
```

But instead it is giving me the following piece of HTML:

```
    &lt;strong&gt;&#252;mlaut&lt;/strong&gt;
```

For completeness, I also mention that the responseEncoding in the web.config is explictely set to utf-8, so I would expect the HtmlEncode method to respect this setting.

```
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
```

Comment: You're correct, `HtmlEncode()` does encode the range U+0080–U+00FF, for no adequately-documented reason. However this shouldn't cause any particular problem; it will just result in marginally larger output (and that too might get compressed away with gzip). Is there a particular problem you need to solve by avoiding encoding for these characters?

Comment: It is not really an issue, more a _cosmetic_ issue. It's just not really necessary. We have semi-technical people editing the html through some kind of CMS and they were all worried why their input came out so bad. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Aristos suggested we could use the AntiXSS library from Microsoft. It contains a [UnicodeCharacterEncoder](http://wpl.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/72192#1652908) that behaves as you would expect.

But because we

- didn't really want to depend on a 3rd party library just for HTML Encoding
- were quite sure that our content didn't exceed the UTF-8 range.

We chose to implement our own *very basic* HTML encoder. You can find the code below. Please feel free to adapt/comment/improve if you see any issues.

```
public static class HtmlEncoder
{
    private static IDictionary<char, string> toEscape = new Dictionary<char, string>()
                                                            {
                                                                { '<', "lt" },
                                                                { '>', "gt" },
                                                                { '"', "quot" },
                                                                { '&', "amp" },
                                                                { '\'', "#39" },
                                                            };
    /// <summary>
    /// HTML-Encodes the provided value
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">object to encode</param>
    /// <returns>An HTML-encoded string representing the provided value.</returns>
    public static string Encode(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return string.Empty;

        // If value is bare HTML, we expect it to be encoded already
        if (value is IHtmlString)
            return value.ToString();

        string toEncode = value.ToString();

        // Init capacity to length of string to encode
        var builder = new StringBuilder(toEncode.Length);

        foreach (char c in toEncode)
        {
            string result;
            bool success = toEscape.TryGetValue(c, out result);

            string character = success
                                ? "&" + result + ";"
                                : c.ToString();

            builder.Append(character);
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes I have the face the same issue with my web pages. 
If we see the code of htmlEncode there is a point that translate this set of characters. Here is the code that this kind of characters also translated.

```
if ((ch >= '\x00a0') && (ch < 'A'))
{
    output.Write("&#");
    output.Write(ch.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
    output.Write(';');
}
else
{
    output.Write(ch);
}
```

Here is the code of HtmlEncode

```
public static unsafe void HtmlEncode(string value, TextWriter output)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        if (output == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("output");
        }
        int num = IndexOfHtmlEncodingChars(value, 0);
        if (num == -1)
        {
            output.Write(value);
        }
        else
        {
            int num2 = value.Length - num;
            fixed (char* str = ((char*) value))
            {
                char* chPtr = str;
                char* chPtr2 = chPtr;
                while (num-- > 0)
                {
                    output.Write(chPtr2[0]);
                    chPtr2++;
                }
                while (num2-- > 0)
                {
                    char ch = chPtr2[0];
                    if (ch <= '>')
                    {
                        switch (ch)
                        {
                            case '&':
                            {
                                output.Write("&amp;");
                                chPtr2++;
                                continue;
                            }
                            case '\'':
                            {
                                output.Write("&#39;");
                                chPtr2++;
                                continue;
                            }
                            case '"':
                            {
                                output.Write("&quot;");
                                chPtr2++;
                                continue;
                            }
                            case '<':
                            {
                                output.Write("&lt;");
                                chPtr2++;
                                continue;
                            }
                            case '>':
                            {
                                output.Write("&gt;");
                                chPtr2++;
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        output.Write(ch);
                        chPtr2++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    // !here is the point!
                    if ((ch >= '\x00a0') && (ch < 'Ā'))
                    {
                        output.Write("&#");
                        output.Write(ch.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
                        output.Write(';');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        output.Write(ch);
                    }
                    chPtr2++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

a Possible solutions is to make your custom HtmlEncode, or use the Anti-Cross Site scripting from MS.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814

Answer (score 0):

based on Thomas's answer , a bit improvement for the space, tab, and new line handling as they might break the structure of html:

```
public static string HtmlEncode(string value,bool removeNewLineAndTabs)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return string.Empty;

        string toEncode = value.ToString();

        // Init capacity to length of string to encode
        var builder = new StringBuilder(toEncode.Length);

        foreach (char c in toEncode)
        {
            string result;
            bool success = toEscape.TryGetValue(c, out result);

            string character = success ? result : c.ToString();

            builder.Append(character);
        }

        string retVal = builder.ToString();

        if (removeNewLineAndTabs)
        {
            retVal = retVal.Replace("\r\n", " ");
            retVal = retVal.Replace("\r", " ");
            retVal = retVal.Replace("\n", " ");
            retVal = retVal.Replace("\t", " ");
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```